# Formating Mail Body data into html table format

Tags: shell-script

I have a hive query result in tab separated format. I am storing it into a file like

```
query="select Name, age from table;"
echo $query | hive > test.csv
```

Now I want to send it in mail using **mutt** command in tabular format.
I am using command:

```
mutt -e -n "set Content-Type:text/html" -s"This is my mail" <test.csv
```

It shows result in mail body as tab separated format I want to make it in tabular format.

query result  is in test file like this. and this is appear in mail body

```
NAME    ssingh
AGE    20
```

Currently It is separated by Tab and I want to convert it in html table format in mail body

Now I am able to generate data in excel 2003 format. Can we convert the excel data into HTML table and send it in mail body using mutt.

Comment: For those of us who don't know hive, can you show us the format of the `test` file (i.e. show us some of the content).

Comment: in addition to what EightBitTony mentioned. It seems want to send the mail in html, when you say tabular do you  mean convert the file to html table? Or do you mean list of values separated by tabs?

Comment: Yes I wan to convert the file data into HTML table

Comment: Is there any option to convert excel data into html table in mail body ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I did it:

First I converted tab separated file into **,** separated file. Here is command

```
sed -i 's/\t/,/g' $filepath/test.csv
```

Now converted **,** separated file into test.html file. Here is code link:

```
http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/118855-convert-csv-html-file.html
```

Then

```
mutt -e -n "set Content-Type:text/html" -s"This is my mail" < test.html
```

This will print file content in html tabular format in mail body

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer to this question, but will help those googling for a solution, for converting bash command output to html table format. There is an easy script available to do this at : https://sourceforge.net/projects/command-output-to-html-table/ which can be used to convert any command output or file to a nice html table format.